# How to Expose field for the current user only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I would serialize the property 'email' of the entity User only if logged user has the same id as the entity.

**Entity User:**

```
@Entity()
@Exclude()
export class User {

    @Expose()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Expose() // Only if logged user == this
    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    public email: string;

    @Expose()
    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    public username: string;

    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    public password: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    public create_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    public update_at: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to conditionally exclude properties based on the object itself. You can use groups though to control the exposure:

```
@Expose({ groups: ['owner'] })
@Column({nullable: true, default: null})
public email: string;
```

and then in your controller you add the group based on your condition:

```
const groups = [];
if (isCurrentUser) {
  groups.push('owner');
}
classToPlain(user, { groups })
```

Comment: I use `ClassSerializerInterceptor` at global level. Do you know if it is possible to add ReflectMetada to it ? 

Like that:
`ReflectMetadata(CLASS_SERIALIZER_OPTIONS, {groups: ['user']});`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know off the top of my head. :-/ Maybe open a new question for it?

Comment: Leaving this here in case anyone stumbles across this. If you want to dynamically add groups (i.e. use `ClassSerializerInterceptor` instead of manually calling `classToPlain`), you can call `Reflect.defineMetadata('class_serializer:options', { groups: 'owner' }, Class.prototype, 'method');`

Comment: @Mr.T awesome nickname. This is what I would like to do soooo much! I tried this instruction in an interceptor but Class.prototype throws error "name Class has not been found". Any idea of what I am missing brother? Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@Entity()
@Exclude()
export class User {

    @Expose()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    public email: string;

    public connectedUser: string?;

    @Expose({ name: 'email'}) // Only if logged user
    public get hideableEmail(): string? {
        if(this.email === this.connectedUser) {
            retun this.email;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Expose()
    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    public username: string;

    @Column({nullable: true, default: null})
    public password: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    public create_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    public update_at: Date;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer !

How can i get the CurrentUser in the Entity ?

Answer (score 0):

as it took me two days to find the most elegant solution, I will leave it here for future reference and to spare people time.
Create an interceptor extending ClassSerializerInterceptor.
N.B. = you will need to have the user registered in the context with his roles

```
import { CallHandler, ClassSerializerInterceptor, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class TransformWithGroupsInterceptor extends ClassSerializerInterceptor {

intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    Reflect.defineMetadata('class_serializer:options', { 'groups': user.roles }, context.getHandler());
    return super.intercept(context, next);
  };
};
```

Then assign the interceptor globally

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
    useClass: LoggingInterceptor,
  }
]})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now you can use for example

```
@Expose({ groups: [Role.Admin] })
```

Best regards